# lwjgl (opengl) texture getting smeared

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm having some trouble with OpenGL in Java (LWJGL), and I was wondering if someone could help me figure it out :-)

Basically, whenever I texture my simple terrain, the texture I have created for it gets smeared. Here's the code to draw a tile

```
private void drawTile(double xPos, double zPos, double height1, double height2, double height3, double height4) {
    GL11.glColor3ub((byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Game.textureId);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    double xIn = xPos * 0.15;
    double xOut = xIn + 0.15;
    double zIn = zPos * 0.15;
    double zOut = zIn + 0.15;

    // System.out.println(xIn + ", " + zIn + " -> " + xOut + ", " + zOut);

    GL11.glVertex3d(xIn, height1, zIn);
    GL11.glTexCoord2d(0d, 0d);

    GL11.glVertex3d(xOut, height2, zIn);
    GL11.glTexCoord2d(1d, 0d);

    GL11.glVertex3d(xOut, height3, zOut);
    GL11.glTexCoord2d(1d, 1d);

    GL11.glVertex3d(xIn, height4, zOut);
    GL11.glVertex2d(0d, 1d);

    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what my texture looks like

[image: grass]

However, this is how it's turning out after I render a 4x4 grid...

[image: Messed up rendering]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 vertex3d calls, 3 texture2d calls and one vertex2d call.  It looks like a simple typo.

```
GL11.glVertex3d(xIn, height4, zOut);
GL11.glVertex2d(0d, 1d);
//   ^^^^^^^^^^ Is not a texture2d call
```

Also, I'm pretty sure you need to be placing the texture2D calls *before* the corresponding vertex call.  A vertex call tells GL that you're finished with that vertex and are moving on to the next one.

Both of these issues end up with the same result.  Two of your vertices (in this case the *north* and *west* vertex) are ending up with the same texture value, so you see the distinctive right triangle with lines as the edge pixels are repeated over the entirety of the triangle.

Try replacing your begin/end contents with this:

```
GL11.glTexCoord2d(0d, 0d);
GL11.glVertex3d(xIn, height1, zIn);

GL11.glTexCoord2d(1d, 0d);
GL11.glVertex3d(xOut, height2, zIn);

GL11.glTexCoord2d(1d, 1d);
GL11.glVertex3d(xOut, height3, zOut);

GL11.glTexCoord2d(0d, 1d);
GL11.glVertex3d(xIn, height4, zOut);
```